# Convert LocalDateTime field

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

In our project we use spring data rest (MongoDB).
Document:

```
@Document(collection = "brands")
@Data
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class BrandDocument {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;

    private String name;
    private Set<String> variants;
}
```

Configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class DictionaryService extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(new Object[]{ DictionaryService.class }, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(BrandDocument.class);
    }
}
```

If i try to GET BrandDocument:

```
curl -X GET -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: c12dbb65-e173-7ff3-2187-bdb6adbdebe9" "http://localhost:7090/typeDocuments/"
```

I will see answer:

```
{
...
   "lastModifiedDate": {
       "content": "2016-08-10T15:50:05.609"
   }
...
}
```

In gradle deps i have for convert java 8 LocalDateTime:

```
compile     group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype',    name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310'
```

If I try to save object, send POST request to http://localhost:7090/typeDocuments/ with content:

```
{
    ...
       "lastModifiedDate": {
           "content": "2016-08-10T15:50:05.609"
       }
    ...
}
```

I have conversion error, but if:

```
{
...
"lastModifiedDate": "2016-08-10T15:50:05.609"
...
}
```

Saved OK.

Why jackson add "content" field for "lastModifiedDate"? And how I can change it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it turned out to be a spring boot / spring data issue, not Jackson.

Spring data scans the data class and detects the field of type `LocalDateTime`. This class is not registered as "simple type" and therefore, it's converted into a `PersistentEntityResource` (with a field named `content`) before serializing it. That's where `content` comes from.

The solution is to register all JSR-310 types as simpe types:

```
@Bean
public MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext() {
    MongoMappingContext context = new MongoMappingContext();
    context.setSimpleTypeHolder(new SimpleTypeHolder(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
            Instant.class,
            LocalDateTime.class,
            LocalDate.class,
            LocalTime.class,
            MonthDay.class,
            OffsetDateTime.class,
            OffsetTime.class,
            Period.class,
            Year.class,
            YearMonth.class,
            ZonedDateTime.class,
            ZoneId.class,
            ZoneOffset.class
    )), MongoSimpleTypes.HOLDER));
    return context;
}
```

Comment: I just saw that it's fixed in spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE, altough there still seems to be a problem with is: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1498

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying anywhere that you want Jackson's `ObjectMapper` to use the serializers/deserializers from `jackson-datatype-jsr310`? If no, you'd have do it like this:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModules(new JavaTimeModule());
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug if your object mapper is used?